# How do I add my SQL Server 2005 database to my VS MVC 2 project?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to use the built-in membership functionality that comes with the SQL Server Express database that is created when the project is built but I want to use it in my SQL Server database without having to re-create the wheel so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Setting up SQL Server with ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/ASPNET/setting-up-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc) it shows you all that you need

Comment: Thanks.  Is it possible to include the aspnetdb tables in the same db with my project data?   The reason I ask is that some hosting providers charge per database.  How do others handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, what you need do is run [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) against your own database, it will add all the database objects into your database.